# Formula for residues of a simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

If we have The rational function:
$$f(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{\psi(z)},~~~~ \phi(z_0)\neq 0 , ~\psi(z_0)=0 , ~\psi'(z_0)\neq 0$$ and the point at $z_0$ is a simple pole, then the residue can be calculated by:
$$\lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{\phi(z)}{\psi(z)}=\frac{\phi(z_0)}{\psi'(z_0)}$$
My question is why can't $\psi'(z_0)=0$ along with $\phi(z_0)=0$ such that they cancel out? For example take the function:
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{e^{2\pi iz^3}-1} \, z_0=0 $$
the formula above gives a result for the residue $\frac{1}{6\pi i}$ where infact the residue is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$

Comment: If $\psi'(z_0)=0$ then $z_0$ is not a simple pole.

Comment: but the example I gave is a simple pole where the bottom part does have derivative of 0

Comment: You don't get $\frac 1 {6\pi i}$ from the formula for the residue. You must have made a mistake.

Comment: Your function violates $\phi(z_0) \neq 0$, as $\phi(z)=z^2$ and $\phi(z_0 = 0) = 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then the residue can be calculated by:
> $$\lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{\phi(z)}{\psi(z)}=\frac{\phi(z_0)}{\psi'(z_0)}\tag{0}$$

Note this formula works under your prerequisite $$\phi(z_0)\neq 0 , ~\psi(z_0)=0 , ~\psi'(z_0)\neq 0\tag{1}$$

But for your new example,

$$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{e^{2\pi iz^3}-1},~~~\phi(z)=z^2,~~\psi(z)= e^{2\pi iz^3}-1,~~z_0=0$$
it doesn't satisfy (1), you can't use (0), otherwise you will get $\frac0 0$. Instead, you can modify (0) and compute the limit by applying L'Hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{\phi(z)}{\psi(z)}=\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{[(z-z_0)\phi(z)]'}{\psi'(z)}=\dots=\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{[(z-z_0)\phi(z)]'''}{\psi'''(z)}\tag{0'}$$

Comment: My question is why is this prerequsite even there. How can I prove that it can't be any other way